HashiCorp Terraform Plugin Framework: Creating a resource with a field set to null
Is there a way to differentiate whether a field was not included in the resource body or if a field was set to null?
I.e
case 1:
resource “foo” “foo” { field1 = “val1” field2 = null }
versus
case 2:
resource “foo” “foo” { field1 = “val1” }
When I set field2’s schema as Optional: true, then in both cases, when I get the plan, field2.IsNull() == true. When I set field2 to Optional: true and Computed: true in the schema, then for both cases field2.IsUnknown == true.
I was wondering if it is at all possible to differentiate knowing if a field was explicitly included in the resource declaration or not (even if the value was set to null).
If not, what would be the best practice to achieve this functionality? I want to be able to pass a null value to fields to explicitly nullify them on resource creation / update. But I dont want this behaviour if the field was not included in the body.
Tried configuring the schema. Used Optional: true, and Computed: true. Since a basetypes.StringValue has a .IsNull() and .IsUnknown() helper functions, though that if I set a value to null, the IsNull() would be true and .IsUnknown() would be false, whereas if I did not include the field in the body, then IsUnknown() would be true. However this is not the case.
